# How do I ensure that my Haskell packages match LTS Haskell?

Tags: haskell, homebrew, cabal-install, haskell-stack

I'd like to have a simple way of ensuring that the packages in my system, whether they are in the global or the user package database, correspond to the versions in the current LTS Haskell.

I gather that there are [fairly simple ways](https://www.stackage.org) to do something like this for a specific project. But it's not clear to me how to achieve this for my Haskell system as a whole. I have Stack installed already (using Cabal), and use Homebrew where I can (e.g., for Haskell, just for `cabal-install`). I'm tempted by [`haskell-stack`](http://brewformulas.org/HaskellStack), but it's unclear what exactly that does.

Is there a simple way to ensure that my system's Haskell packages (wherever they reside) match LTS Haskell?

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using cabal-install, your best bet is to append the contents of https://www.stackage.org/lts-3.8/cabal.config?global=true (adjust the LTS snapshot slug to your preference) to your `~/.cabal/config`.  I'd caution against doing this, though, since you may well want to use different snapshots for different projects.  Use of sandboxes with cabal-install is highly recommended (in fact, I set `require-sandbox: true` in my cabal config to make sure I don't forget).

For Stack, the LTS snapshot is always project-specific; there is no global setting.  But setting the `resolver:` value in `~/.stack/global/stack.yaml` sets it for when you run `stack` outside of a specific project, and also influences the choice of resolver for new projects (when you use `stack init` or `stack new`).

BTW, it looks like the Homebrew `haskell-stack` formula is just an alternate way to install Stack, so if you already have Stack there's no need to use it.